# How to send name without picking a date and send it to coud firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want when i enter a name and optionally pick a date. I want to send the name or data even if i didn't pick a date to cloud_firestore. I tried doing if the user didn't picked a date, then null will be sent to the database. but reading it back is a problem.

I include a image on what i want to do.[image: This is what i want to do]

This is the code

```
 final TextEditingController _dateController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();
  final DateTime date = DateTime.now();
  DateTimeUtils dateTimeUtils = DateTimeUtils();
  NameServices nameServices = NameServices();
  bool isFalse = false;
  bool userPickedDate = false;
  String text = 'Please enter a text';

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _dateController.dispose();
    _textController;
    super.dispose();
  }

  void isCheckedTextField() {
    setState(() {
      if (_textController.text.isEmpty) {
        isFalse = true;
      } else if (_dateController.text.isEmpty) {
        userPickedDate = true;
      } else {
        isFalse = false;
        nameServices.sendData(
          _textController.text,
          DateFormat.yMMMd().parse(_dateController.text),
        );
        _textController.clear();
      }
    });

    _dateController.clear();
  }

  Future<DateTime?> selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? pickedDate = await dateTimeUtils.getDate(
      context: context,
      firstDate: DateTime(2020),
      lastDate: DateTime(2080),
      initialDate: date,
    );

    if (pickedDate != null) {
      setState(() {
        _dateController.text = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(pickedDate);
      });
    }
    return pickedDate;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 200),
              child: CustomButton(
                textController: _textController,
                onSubmitted: (value) {
                  _textController.text = value;
                },
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() => isFalse = false);
                },
                dateController: _dateController,
                onTap: () {
                  selectDate(context);
                },
                onPressed: () {
                  isCheckedTextField();
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: nameServices.getData(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        DocumentSnapshot document = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                        final docName = document['name'];
                        int docDate = document['date'];
                        DateTime dateTime =
                            DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(docDate);
                        NameModel dName =
                            NameModel(firstName: docName, date: dateTime);
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            dName.firstName,
                          ),
                          subtitle: Text(
                            DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(dName.date),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                }
                return const SizedBox();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

This is the CRUD

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class NameServices {
  //Get the collection:
  final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

  //SEND:
  Future sendData(String name, DateTime? date) async {
    try {
      int? selectedDate = date?.millisecondsSinceEpoch;

      await db.add(
        {
          "name": name,
          'date': selectedDate,
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error sending data: $e');
    }
  }

  //READ
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getData() {
    return db.orderBy('date', descending: true).snapshots();
  }

  //UPDATE
  Future updateName(String docID, String name) {
    return db.doc(docID).update({'name': name});
  }

  //DELETE
  Future<void> deleteName(String docID) {
    return db.doc(docID).delete();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your build you have the following:

```
 ListTile(
   title: Text(
     username.text,
   ),
   subtitle: Text(
     DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(dName.date),
   ),
 ),
```

You get an error because you are trying to display a date that returns a null value. Since flutter has null safety, you have to specify what to replace it with if it returns null like this:

```
DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(dName.date) ?? ''
```

The `??` indicates what to replace it with if null is returned.